# How to patch a function that a Flask view calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-web-services

My webapp wants to send a message to AWS SQS with boto and I'd want to mock out sending the actual message and just checking that calling send_message is called. However I do not understand how to use python mock to patch a function that a function being tested calls.

How could I achieve mocking out boto con.send_message as in the pseudo-like code below?

views.py:

```
@app.route('/test')
def send_msg():
    con = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("eu-west-1",aws_access_key_id="asd",aws_secret_access_key="asd")
    que = con.get_queue('my_queue')
    msg = json.dumps({'data':'asd'})
    r=con.send_message(que, msg)
```

tests.py

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_test(self):
        with patch('views.con.send_message') as sqs_send:
            self.test_client.get('/test')
            assert(sqs_send.called)
```

Comment: Are your still interested on this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this kind of test you need `patch` `connect_to_region()`. When this method is patched return a `MagicMock()` object that you can use to test all your function behavior.

Your test case can be something like this one:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("boto.sqs.connect_to_region", autospec=True)
    def test_test(self, mock_connect_to_region):
        #grab the mocked connection returned by patched connect_to_region
        mock_con = mock_connect_to_region.return_value
        #call client
        self.test_client.get('/test')
        #test connect_to_region call
        mock_connect_to_region.assert_called_with("eu-west-1",aws_access_key_id="asd",aws_secret_access_key="asd")
        #test get_queue()
        mock_con.get_queue.assert_called_with('my_queue')
        #finaly test send_message
        mock_con.send_message.assert_called_with(mock_con.get_queue.return_value, json.dumps({'data':'asd'}))
```

Just some notes:

1. I wrote it in a *white box* style and check all calls of your view: you can do it more loose and omit some checks; use `self.assertTrue(mock_con.send_message.called)` if you want just check the call or use `mock.ANY` as argument if you are not interested in some argument content.
2. `autospec=True` is not mandatory but very useful: take a look at [autospeccing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing).
3. I apologize if code contains some error... I cannot test it now but I hope the idea is clear enough.